# Redeclaration of name of class type

Tags: c++, class, declaration

Consider the following example:

```
void foo()
{
    class A;
    class A;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And it is work fine. Why such redecration of class type is permitted? I'm confused...

UPD: Please give me a quote from c++ spec where such redeclaration is permitted... if it possible.

Answer (score 1):

§ 3.1
A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a translation unit **or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations.**

Thats in the first clause.

The second clause specifies whats a declaration. I didnt copy it here because it includes quite a few examples.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

`Declaration` and `Definition` are two different concepts. You can declare a name any number of times you want in a translation unit. But the definition should appear only once. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if each class A is declared in different cpp files as global variables
the linker will raise a warn if you invoke g++ with "-warn-common"